# Is Dick Cheney still supporting Donald Trump for re-election in 2020, given his recent public support for wearing face masks?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, vice-president

Dick Cheney supported Donald Trump in 2016 (in the general election), and indications were that he was going to support Trump in 2020 as well. In August 2019, he [appeared at a fundraiser for Trump's 2020 campaign](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/dick-cheney-trump-2020-fundraiser-campaign-republican-party-establishment-a9064666.html).

More recently, his daughter and Representative Liz Cheney tweeted a photo of Dick Cheney wearing a mask, presumably to try to counter the anti-mask posture of the Trump administration. It doesn't seem that Cheney was all that public in his support of Trump previously; is he still supporting Trump's reelection regardless?

Comment: One doesn't need to 100% agree to support someone. Your premise seems to be that support equals 100% agreement.

Comment: Face mask =/= political affiliation.

Answer (score 3):

Dick Cheney does not write 5 tweets before breakfast each day, and can reasonably be described as retired.  We therefore don't have daily reports on his current voting intentions.

His daughter Liz Cheney, who posted the photograph of her father in a mask, is clearly an independent person who may or may not agree with her father on particular points.  But it is clear that both Dick Cheney and his daughter think it is important to wear a mask at times.

Liz Cheney is also critical of the Trump administration on a number of other policy areas, such as reducing US troop numbers in Germany.

But Liz Cheney supports Donald Trump's re-election. She recently described Biden as "[completely unserious and unfit to lead.](https://twitter.com/Liz_Cheney/status/1270068269014306821?s=20)".  There is no reason to believe that former Republican Vice President Dick Cheney is not also supporting Trump. If he were publically rejecting Trump, this would be major political news. Just because a politician disagrees on one particular policy, does not mean that they fully reject the whole program and will campaign against re-election.